# Flat File Formatting in Console Application c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

All ,

I have a Flat File where I want to remove the empty line at the end or middle and the extra header. Below is the formats

Expected Format :

```
addsad, sadasd                                          |sdsf-sdff-sfg  |sffdff, sdfadgg , fg                 |04/15/20 12:30|sd sf 36                                   
24567      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24568      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24569      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24579      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24571      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24572      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24573      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24574      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24575      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24576      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24577      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24578      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24579      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24581      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24582      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24583      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh
```

[image]
Wrong Format-1: (There are empty lines at the end which I have highlight as *  )

```
addsad, sadasd                                          |sdsf-sdff-sfg  |sffdff, sdfadgg , fg                 |04/15/20 12:30|sd sf 36                                   
24567      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24568      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24569      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24579      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24571      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24572      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24573      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24574      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     


                                                                                                                                                                         
addsad, sadasd                                          |sdsf-sdff-sfg  |sffdff, sdfadgg , fg                 |04/15/20 12:30|sd sf 36                                   
24575      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24576      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24577      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24578      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24579      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24581      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24582      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24583      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh
```

[image]

Wrong Format-2 :

```
addsad, sadasd                                          |sdsf-sdff-sfg  |sffdff, sdfadgg , fg                 |04/15/20 12:30|sd sf 36                                   
24567      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24568      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24569      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24579      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24571      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24572      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24573      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh                                                                                     
24574      |dsfg gfdgg fghjN                                        |1         |fhhh
```

[image]

Code written : (This is removing all the empty lines alone )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)


        {

            String sourceDirectory = @"C:\Console\New folder\In.txt";
            String targetDirectory = @"C:\Console\New folder\Out.txt";

            string text = File.ReadAllText(sourceDirectory);
             text = text.Trim(' ', '\r', '\n');
            File.AppendAllText(targetDirectory, text + Environment.NewLine);



        }
    }
}
```

Requirement : Need to Format the Wrong Format File so i can get the expected format , Need to remove the Empty line expect the first line and remove the duplicate header.Attached the picture for reference

Comment: Yeah, this is easy enough (within reason). However, its a hack to solve a problem somewhere else. Id suggest fixing that (if you can)

Comment: If you really really need to do this, you will have to give us a rule on what denotes a header. We can write magic methods to read your mind or pseudo data

Comment: Header will be always the second line , First line will be always empty , second line will be always header

Comment: That's all well and good, however you said "*remove the duplicate header*", how do we know what is a header as compared to actual data? Which information is in, special, and unique to a header, that we know we can safely delete a duplicate header? `addsad` is not good enough... Note i still recommend fixing the program that creates this file

Comment: whatever comes in the second line "Addsad" is unique header  for that file , if that is  been repeated in the same file in different line then we have to remove it. In the wrong format I have provided "Addsad" is repeated in line 14 as shown in the pic  which should be removed along with the empty line Hope this explains ?

Comment: I'm guessing there's another process creating multiple files, which get appended together. I'd suggest either changing that program, or appending the files in this program instead.

Comment: @TheGeneral, The pattern seems pretty obvious to me, every header row has one or more whitespace rows before it. Every header row is followed by zero or more data rows until the row is empty or consists of whitespaces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your case, when you know what your data looks like, I'd approach it slightly differently and just do ...

```
    var all = File.ReadAllLines(sourceDirectory).ToList();
    var dataLines = all.Where(l => Regex.IsMatch(l, @"^\d+"));
    var lines = all.Take(2).Concat(dataLines).ToList(); 
    File.WriteAllLines(targetDirectory, lines);
```

not sure if you want the first blank line, if you don't  then make it `all.Skip(1).Take(1)`

Comment: According to the authors description, `all.Take(1)` would result in an empty line...

Comment: @Shazi he can customize it, but yeah, seems he wants a Take(2)

Answer (score 1):

Try writing line by line and ignore the line and next line (header) if you come accross an empty line.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ignoreNext = false;
    using var stream = new StreamWriter("targetFile.txt", true);
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("sourceFile.txt"))
    {

        if (line == null || line.Trim() == string.Empty)
        {
            ignoreNext = true;
        }
        else if (!ignoreNext)
        {
            stream.WriteLine(line);
        }
        else
        {
            ignoreNext = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is sourceFile:
[image]

And targetFile:
[image]

Comment: Its not working, i am getting "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'valuye' of 'string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String)

Comment: @sukra I updated the answer, tried it and it works.

Comment: @TheGeneral It is actually working, i just changed it to `ReadLines` as you suggested for performance.

Comment: Ahh yup, my mistake

Comment: This is the answer I would go with. I might have replaced the `line == null || line.Trim() == string.Empty` for a `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line)` to make it more readable.

Comment: @1.44mb the code works fine with the WrongFormat-1 , i tried with WrongFormat-2 where it is removing the first two lines. I have updated my question with the wrong Format -2

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't do the work for you for all scenarios. You can get the idea from my answer and work your way.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
private void FixFile (string filename)
{ 
    //read existing file
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

    //overwrite existing file
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename, false))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            //trim leading/trailing spaces
            string currentLine = lines[i].Trim();

            //skip additional headers - header lines contain a date which has '/'
            if (i >= 2 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentLine) && !currentLine.Contains('/'))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(currentLine);
            }
            else if (i < 2)
            {
                //keep first two lines
                sw.WriteLine(currentLine);
            }
        }

        //clean up
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();

    }
}
```